# I've created an event countdown timer using Django. So the expected output is this: Event Countdown Timer Diwali Fest Time Remaining: 29 : 24 : 09

Tags: html, django-views

Event Countdown Timer
Time Remaining:
NaN : NaN : NaN

I tried to create an event countdown timer so that it generates how much time is left for the event & it displays the countdown until that time occurs. but unfortunately it isn't displaying the timer and also the festival name, which it is supposed to show.